# In Matlab how can I control the color iterator when plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to make a bunch of plots (or subplots) with the same color, then advance to next color, make a bunch plots again, and so on and so forth. Using the default colors are fine. Also my number of plots may exceed the number of colors in the default so I will need to cycle through it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an axes, it has the property `ColorOrderIndex` which refers to the index of the next color to be used. The initial value of `ColorOrderIndex` is `1`, and each time you add a new plot to the same axes (without clearing, that is, with using `hold on`), the value increases and cycles through all the colors (which are themselves stored in the property `ColorIndex` as a 2d matrix with three columns, where each row represents an RGB triplet. This matrix has a default value, consisting of 7 colors (in Matlab R2015a), but you can assign any other colors you want to it).
Thus, by manually making sure that the value of the `ColorOrderIndex` property does not increase, you can keep the same color for the next plot.

```matlab
ax = axes;
hold on;
numberOfColors = length(ax.ColorOrder);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = 1;

plot([0,0],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = mod(ax.ColorOrderIndex-2,numberOfColors)+1; % keep same color
plot([1,1],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = mod(ax.ColorOrderIndex-2,numberOfColors)+1; % keep same color
plot([2,2],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);

% change color
plot([3,3],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = mod(ax.ColorOrderIndex-2,numberOfColors)+1; % keep same color
plot([4,4],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);


% change color
plot([5,5],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = mod(ax.ColorOrderIndex-2,numberOfColors)+1; % keep same color
plot([6,6],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = mod(ax.ColorOrderIndex-2,numberOfColors)+1; % keep same color
plot([7,7],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);
ax.ColorOrderIndex = mod(ax.ColorOrderIndex-2,numberOfColors)+1; % keep same color
plot([8,8],[0,1],'LineWidth',2);

% and so on...
```

[image: Output of above code]

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this satisfy your requirements? If you have a lot of charts with colors changing frequently, you could create a dictionary with index time (when the color switch should occur) as the key and the color as the value. The code below is simpler though.

```
% Colors for 10 red plots and 5 black plots
colors = [repmat('r', 1, 10), repmat('b', 1, 5)];
for i = 1:length(colors)
    figure; plot(x, y, colors(i));
end
```

Comment: No that wouldn't work because it's not pre-defined how many plots I will make for each color.

Comment: Comments in MATLAB don't use the # symbol, you might want to change that

Answer (score 0):

Every time you plot, you could just randomly select the color:

```
% Create a random RGB color
color = rand(1,3);

% Plot as many times as needed with the newly created random color
plot (X,Y,'color', color)
```

You can loop through this as many times as necessary